# Can't connect to PostgreSQL in Rstudio, possible permissions issue?

Tags: r, postgresql, rstudio

I've followed the documentation on db.rstudio.com and other sites, and I'm not able to connect to my Postgres database from Rstudio. I'm on macos 10.14. Running:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver = "PostgreSQL Driver",
                       Database = "mydatabase",
                       UID = "myuser",
                       PWD = "mypassword",
                       Host = "localhost",
                       Port = 5432)
```

Gives the error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000:
```

At first, I got an empty list when running `odbcListDrivers()`, however I was able to get it to show the postgres driver location/value by copying `odbcinst.ini` from the global `/etc` to my user (`cp /etc/odbcinst.ini ~/.odbcinst.ini`).

Similarly, `odbcListDataSources()` returned nothing until I did the same thing (`cp /etc/odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini`)

The `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` are locked from editing via Finder, but can be edited via nano/terminal.

I also tried to solve the problem by installing the database drivers via Postgres' stack builder, but it didn't change anything.

Overall I'm suspecting that it's a permissions issue, but I'm not quite sure where to look next.

Thanks for your help!

---

The permission for the `odbc.ini` was:

```
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 root  wheel   139B Mar 31 12:57 odbc.ini
```

Which I changed to:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myuser  wheel   139B Mar 31 12:57 odbc.ini
```

But that didn't solve the problem, the error is the same.

---

The content of `odbcinst.ini` is:

```
[PostgreSQL Driver]
Driver = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
```

The content of `odbc.ini` is:

```
[PostgreSQL]
Driver = PostgreSQL Driver
Database = mydatabase
Servername = localhost
UserName = myuser
Password = mypassword
Port = 5432
```

---

`odbc::odbcListDrivers()` gives:

```
 name       attribute
1 PostgreSQL Driver          Driver
2      ODBC Drivers Amazon Redshift
3   Amazon Redshift          Driver
                                                           value
1                                    /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
2                                                      Installed
3 /opt/amazon/redshift/lib/universal/libamazonredshiftodbc.dylib
```

`odbc::odbcListDataSources()` gives:

```
        name       description
1 PostgreSQL PostgreSQL Driver
```

Comment: I updated the question with the info and deleted comments, thanks.

Comment: Try lower case of your connection arguments due to case sensitivity (i.e., *driver*, *database*, etc.). Alternatively, try DSN connection: `con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "PostgreSQL")`.

Comment: Somehow it now works. The database is showing up in the connections pane. I have no idea what changed. I had already tried both lower case and DSN connection. Anyway thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Which version of the trials I suggested worked? Can you re-try with titled cases for args and see if that fails? I can officially answer to help future readers who run into your same issue.

Comment: Of course. However, the methods that work now did not work 15 minutes ago. But: Lower and upper case in the console and the Connections GUI/dialogue all work. DSN also works. So I'm still confused about what solved it.